# Add trailing slash before ProxyPass to other domain

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, trailing-slash

I've got this set up on my apache configuration file:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/webdocs/(.*)$ http://other-domain/webdocs/$1 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse ^/webdocs/(.*)$ http://other-domain/webdocs/$1 retry=0
```

So when users access to the subdirectory webdocs in my webserver, I proxypass them to this other-domain server.

When I access to:

http://my-domain/webdocs/example/

Everything works fine and the project works as expected.

However, if I access to

http://my-domain/webdocs/example (without trailing slash)

Then a redirection happens and I can see on my address bar the next url:

http://other-domain/webdocs/example/

Any idea why this is happening? I tried many times to rewrite url so I could add a trailing slash before proxy pass, but then all the requests to files have the trailing slash added as well so the project doesn't run properly (assets not found). I tried something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^/webdocs(.*)$ /webdocs$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Try modifying ProxyPassReverse line to `ProxyPassReverse /webdocs/ http://other-domain/webdocs/` and see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.. exaclty the same result

Comment: (I assume you did but still) make sure you restart httpd and test from clean browser (without cache)

Comment: Hi Dusan. Exactly, I restarted the service and tried from an incognito tab...

Comment: can you try `curl -v http://other-domain/webdocs/example` and check what is in `Location` response header

Comment: The response code is `301 (moved permanently)` and the `Location` is `http://other-domain/webdocs/example/` (notice the trailing slash there...) Does this explain the problem? thanks

Comment: Yes, it explains the problem, but AFAIK my first suggestion to modify `ProxyPassReverse..` should handle that, so I am out of ideas